# GCC compiler errors with primitive type definitons

Tags: c, linux, gcc

So upon upgrading to Linux Mint(and using GCC v4.7.3) some headers have been generating some very odd compiler errors. When I try to compile  I get the following error messages:

```
gcc s.c
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/setjmp.h:26:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/bits/pthreadtypes.h:14,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/pthread.h:14,
                 from s.c:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/bits/setjmp.h:30:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘typedef’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/bits/pthreadtypes.h:14:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/pthread.h:14,
                 from s.c:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/setjmp.h:46:5: error: unknown type name ‘__jmp_buf’

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Nov 25 09:03:37
```

So this is the  header which is triggering the compiler error(s):

```
/* Define the machine-dependent type `jmp_buf'.  x86-64 version.  */
#ifndef _BITS_SETJMP_H
#define _BITS_SETJMP_H  1

#include <bits/wordsize.h>

# if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int __jmp_buf[8];
# else
typedef int __jmp_buf[6];
# endif

#endif  /* bits/setjmp.h */
```

And here is the source code(s.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Can you reduce `s.c` to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: looks to me like you don't have the `bits/wordsize.h` file or it is the thing that has a problem since it is directly before the error.

Comment: It would be very useful to see the output of `gcc -E s.c`. Since it'll be a large file, I'd recommend putting it on somthing like gist.github.com

Comment: Is that _really_ the source code? Do you by any chance have your own header included before `pthread.h`? That way, a problem in the bottom of _your_ include file would cause a problem noticeable in the next innocent include file.

Comment: @Shahbaz: That is likely the original code, if you notice the original error messages, the include to `pthread.h` is on the second line of s.c, which it also is in the code he has shown.

Comment: The error is seing here but is located somewhere else, as the compiler didn't expect the typedef in that position. What do you include before including pthread.h?

Comment: The header that's causing the problem for <pthread.h> is the header <bits/pthreadtypes.h>

Comment: pthreadtypes.h uses the following headers:

Comment: #include <bits/wordsize.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/futex.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

Comment: All of these headers compile by themselves FTR.

Comment: @MrX: Could I see the output of `gcc -E s.c`? That gives the output of the compiler after preprocessing input files. It would give a great deal of insight into the issue.

Comment: Do you compile with option `-pthread`?

Comment: alk, I did not. I will try that and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I googled "linux pthreadtypes" and found another version of  at code dot woboq dot org that is Linux specific. It compiles nicely so I scrubbed the existing version of the header that gave me the errors that I posted about earlier. Not sure where I got that version from but it was somewhere on the Internet and may very well have been the FreeBSD version.Gotta make sure your POSIX thread headers/libraries are compatible with your OS.

Comment: Those headers should come with the compiler or O/S. Installing your own versions of the headers is a recipe for disaster — as it appears you've now found out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler at least it was compilation error. But if it would compile... Don't even want to imagine what it _could_ be.